# Objective-C runtime - how to use setValue to set a CGRect

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

How do I set an instance's property when that property is a CGRect.  I want to do this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectFromString(value);
[localClassObjectInstance setValue:rect forKey:key];
```

but the compiler doesn't like the setValue; it says I'm sending CGRect to parameter of incompatible type 'id'.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must transform a CGRect to NSValue (and viceversa):

```
NSValue *myValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];
```

NSValue is an object (so it's of type "id").

Then you can get the CGRect back with:

```
CGRect myRect = [myValue CGRectValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSValue` and `NSNumber` are to handle cases when the value is not an obj-c object:

```
NSRect rect = ...;
[object setValue:[NSValue valueWithRect:rect] forKey:key];

NSValue* val = [object valueForKey:key];
NSRect extractedRect = [val rectValue];
```

To store `GCRect` with Mac OS X SDK, you have to convert it to `NSRect` first using `NSRectFromCGRect` and `NSRectToCGRect` functions. On iOS, there are  `valueWithCGRect`/`CGRectValue` methods instead (see @viggio24 answer).